# how to get user details related to chatter live agent?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I enable live agent user checkbox in salesforce user details page?

if the live agent going to create a new case i need to get those user details how to achieve this?

and if i enable checkbox in multiple users how to get details dynamically?

please suggest SOQL

Thanks,
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm), the API name of the field is `UserPermissionsLiveAgentUser`.

> Type: boolean
>
> Properties: Create, Filter, Update
>
> Description: Indicates whether the user is enabled to use Live Agent (true) or not (false). Label is **Live Agent User**.

So in order to get a List of Users who have this ticked, the query you're looking for is:

```
[SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE UserPermissionsLiveAgentUser = true]
```

Check that you actually have a `Contact` related to the `User`. Using your query in the comments below, I was able to successfully get related `Contacts`.

[image]

Comment: User UserDetails = [SELECT Id, username, user.Contact.Name, user.Contact.Account.Name FROM User WHERE UserPermissionsLiveAgentUser = true ];

 
i wrote the query like this but i didn't get the user details please verify once

Comment: @chandra I'm guessing you've got more than one User? In which case you'd need to return an array. So instead of doing `User UserDetails = [...]`, do `List<User> UserDetails = [...]`. I'm surprised you didn't get an error about that.

Comment: with as you are given query i get the total live agent user but i need to get those user related contact name retrieving is there any change in my query 

List<User> UserDetails = [SELECT Id, username, user.Contact.Name, user.Contact.Account.Name FROM User WHERE UserPermissionsLiveAgentUser = true ];

Comment: @chandra Those User records definitely have a related Contact? See the edit, I've ran the exact same query and got results (had to redact the details though).